# Declaring variables before use in old C

Tags: c, gcc, c89

Recently I had to modify a legacy code that was compiled with a very old version of GCC (somewhere around version 2.3). Within a function, variable had to be declared before being used. I believe this is done C89 standard. This limitation is later removed.

My question is: Back then, why did they enforce this ruling? Was there any concern that could jeopardise the integrity of the software?

Comment: Are you asking why we declare variables at all?  Or are you asking why are variables declared at the beginning of a function?  The way you phrased your question is very odd.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Variables still have to be declared before being used -- and they've never had to be declared just at the top of a function.

The C89 requirement is that a block consists of an opening `{`, followed by zero or more declarations, followed by zero or more statements, followed by the closing `}`.

For example, this is legal C89 (and, without the `void`, even K&R C, going back to 1978 or earlier):

```
int foo(void) {
    int outer = 10;
    {
         int inner = 20;
         printf("outer = %d, inner = %d\n", outer, inner);
    }
    printf("outer = %d, inner is not visible\n", outer);
    return 0;
}
```

C99 loosened this, allowing declarations and statements to be mixed within a block:

```
int foo(void) {
    int x = 10;
    printf("x = %d\n", x);
    int y = 20;
    printf("y = %d\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

As for the reason for the original restriction, I think it goes back to C's ancestor languages: B, BCPL, and even Algol.  It probably did make the compiler's job a bit easier.  (I was thinking that it would make parsing easier, but I don't think it does; it still has to be able to distinguish whether something is a declaration or a statement without knowing in advance from the context.)

Comment: Yes, but I much prefer the "declare at top" style.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: There's something to be said for declaring variables close to their use, and especially for being able to take advantage of previous statements in initializers.

Comment: I don't understand "being able to take advantage of previous statements in initializers".

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: A shamelessly contrived example: `{ int x = 42; if (cond) x ++; int y = x * 2; }`

Comment: Ah, I see. I like having all variables on top as sort of a manifest.

Comment: @Amigable Clark Kant Steve Connell talks about variable "live time" in his book, Code-Complete. By declaring variables as close to their use as possible, the chances of introducing a bug is reduced. However, I do agree that it makes for hard reading sometimes.

Comment: @thegreendroid, I know this argument, but to me it does not hold water. To me the type declarations are noise inserted among the statements. Instead, I tend to break up functions in smaller, that's my way to manage.  But much writing comes down to style.

Comment: @Amigable Clark Kant I agree that it is not aesthetically pleasing, it's definitely not easy on the eyes. I would still prefer to declare at the top even of that increases the 'live time'. But like you said, live time only increases when you have big functions so it all comes down to how you structure your code.

Comment: @KeithThompson, it definitely made the job of the compiler easier. You could just count the variables, add how many bytes they took, and then advance the stack pointer with as much, with one instruction, and then know the functions stack was taken care of. A very simple, one to one relation between C statements and machine code.

Answer (score 4):

It was mainly to make compilers easier to write. If all the declarations were at the top of the function, it would be easy for the compiler to parse all the locals and determine how much stack is needed.

Of course now, compilers are a lot more mature than they were 30 years ago. So it makes sense to get rid of this restriction as it's become a nuisance to programmers.

Comment: Nevertheless, I think the code is cleaner and easier to read and maintain if you declare all the variables at the beginning of a function. But I admit, sometimes it can be a bit annoying to write code that way.

Comment: It was always possible to introduce new variables at the start of any block of code - before the first non-declaration statement.  Thus `void function(int i) { int j; { int k; ...; } ...; }` was always valid (with appropriate code in place of the ellipses, of course).